# Questions about company types

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic, site-information

I would like to ask a question about forming different company types, i.e. LLC vs. S-corp.

My dad asked me about this and I want to repeat the answer I gave him about the comparative advantages and risks, to get answers on how accurate my answer was and if there are important details that I may have missed.

Would this be on topic here? If not, could I have a SE site recommendation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, this type of question is on-topic here.

According to our [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions about sole proprietorships are generally on-topic.  An example sub-category that is explicitly mentioned as on-topic is "When to incorporate to protect your work or assets."  It follows that the pros and cons of incorporating your sole-proprietorship as an LLC vs S-corp is also on-topic.

However, keep in mind that this site is primarily about *personal* finance.  If your question delves too deep into business finance or is about a larger business, it will not be well-received here.

Alternatively, if you decide that your question is not related enough to *personal* finance, you could try [Startups.SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/).